# Why do I need to write "datetime" twice?

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner with python. In the following code, I imported the "datetime" module and I wanted to get current date and time. But why do I need to write "datetime" twice?

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: `datetime` is a module, with an attribute `datetime` in it. To access that attribute, you therefore need `datetime.datetime`,

Answer (score 5):

You are importing a module named [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

Due to an unfortunate lack of imagination, one of the classes defined in the `datetime` module is *also* named [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects). It is that class that defines a class method named [`now`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

There are other classes defined in the module: `datetime.date`, `datetime.time`, `datetime.timedelta`, etc.

An alternate way of writing this is to import the name of the class directly into the local namespace.

```
from datetime import datetime

# Now 'datetime' refers to the class, not the module.
now = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Python provides the datetime module to work with real dates and times. From that about code the first `datetime` is the module and other `datetime` is class and remaining (`now`) is the method.